# Al guardar una fecha me resta un día al revisar en la BD

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc, jquery-mobile

Estoy utilizando Spring MVC 4 e Hibernate 4, al momento de guardar una fecha desde la interfaz de usuario la cual esta implementada con JQuery Mobile, al revisar los registros de la base de datos siempre la fecha me resta un día. 
Ejemplo: En la interfaz de usuario selecciono la fecha 04-09-1999. Al revisar el registro en la base de datos(PostgreSQL) me aparece la fecha pero con un día menos 1999-09-03. 
Este es el codigo del cliente para elegir la fecha

```
<div class="ui-field-contain">
  <label for="usufecnac">Fecha Nacimiento</label>
  <input type="date" name="usufecnac" id="usufecnac" />
</div>
```

Este es una parte del código de la clase de la entidad en java.

```
*
import java.util.Date;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Temporal;
import javax.persistence.TemporalType;
import org.springframework.format.annotation.DateTimeFormat;
import org.springframework.format.annotation.DateTimeFormat.ISO;

private Date usufecnac;

@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
@DateTimeFormat(iso = ISO.DATE)
@Column(name="usufecnac", nullable=false, length=13)
public Date getUsufecnac() {
    return this.usufecnac;
}
```

Comment: No lo quiero poner como respuesta pues no estoy muy seguro, pero a mi me pasaba que me registraba un día de más, lo que hice fue agarrar el día y restarle uno jaja pero me imagino que tiene que ver directamente con el UTC, puedes revisarlo a ver.

Comment: @LuisMorales Podrías explicarme mejor a lo que te refieres, como es que podría hacer lo que estas diciendo disculpa mi ignorancia. Gracias.

Comment: en SO hay una respuesta muy detalla del manejo de fechas con JavaScript http://stackoverflow.com/a/31732581/890839

Comment: cuando instalas el motor de BD el te pide que le ingreses la zona horaria, por ahi puede estar el error

Comment: @MrDev no creo que sea el motor de base de datos ya que cuando registro una fecha con el sistema me captura fecha y hora correctamente, el problema creo que viene desde Java que es donde estoy desarrollando la aplicación.

Comment: Estas usando java 1.8 para compilar el proyecto?

Comment: @RaulCacacho asi es. al ingresar a propiedades del proyecto desde netbeans, al ir a la opción de Build -> Compile, en Java Platform sale JDK 1.8(default). ¿Hay algún inconveniente con esto, conoce alguna solución?

Comment: Si he visto q no funciona bien guarda un año menos voy a ponerte como las guardo yo

Answer (score 1):

El problema me he dado cuenta que cuando **compilas** tu proyecto con con **java 8** las fechas no se almacenan correctamente pero puedes utilizar la libreria de localDate que es la que viene en java 8 te dejo un ejemplo de como utilizarla

```
import org.springframework.format.annotation.DateTimeFormat;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController; 
import java.time.LocalDate;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/datetime/")
final class DateTimeController {

@RequestMapping(value = "date", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public void processDate(@RequestParam("date") 
                        @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "dd/MM/yyyy") LocalDate date) {
    //Tu codigo 
}
}
```